# Flipping Numbers - Cant figure it out

Tags: java

### Flipping Numbers

Given a list of N unique integers, 2 <= N <= 25000, produce a sequence of flips so that the end result is the list, sorted in ascending order.

A k-flip takes the first k numbers and reverses their order in the list. 
For example given the list `(2; 6; 4; 1; 9)`,
a k-flip where k = 4 would result in the list `(1; 4; 6; 2; 9)`.

Your task is to determine a list of k values which represent the sequence of flips that will result in list being sorted.

### Input

The first line of input contains the integer N which represents the number of integers in the list. The next line of input contains N space-separated integers.

### Output

Your program should output the sequence of k values which represent the flips that turn the input list in to a sorted list. Each of these values should be separated by a space and the output should be terminated by a new line character.

### Sample Input 1

```
5
1 4 6 2 9
```

### Sample Output 1

```
3 4 2
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What have you tried so far?

Comment: we are more than able to help you sort out your logic for the correct answer, but let us know what you have been working on.

Comment: Please, read [this (how to ask)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and
[this (mcve)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before asking,
as those will help you get more and better answers from the community.

Comment: @Bonatti I don't think those are applicable at all! This question is well written and clear, although OP hasn't shown any of his work.

Comment: @darren People on this site will generally appreciate it if you show what you have tried so far.

Comment: @Rishav While is true that the user wrotte a "well written" question, with formatting and all, my links point to this site guidelines on the best practices expected... the MCVE specially

Comment: @Rishav I disagree. This question is terrible. It's a pasted challenge that is more suited to codegolf.stackexchange.com. The only "question" is in the title where it says "Cant figure it out". That's it.

Comment: *"questions... must include... **a specific problem or error**..."*